# Can you ddos a server by just requesting for static assets?

Tags: ddos

I noticed that a lot of web apps don't have authorization protection around static assets such as img/fonts. Can you ddos these servers by just asking for its logo image a billion times?

Answer (score 0):

Usually these are served by separate infrastructure, even if they share a domain. In this case, as long as you're not sending enough traffic to knock over the load balancers, it would be difficult to screw up the actual API endpoints.

That said, yes, you can cause DDoS by requesting static assets. You can do even do it below the application layer by doing things like flooding your target with bogus, spoofed, UDP traffic. This is in fact the usual way that such attacks manifest, since there exist ways to amplify this traffic with unsecured 3rd party servers, and this is much harder to do with HTTP requests.

Anything that the public can do which uses any resources at all can be scaled up into a DDoS. The only question is whether the target can withstand or mitigate the attack.